# Pytorch batch matrix-matrix outer product

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, elementwise-operations

Similarly to the question in [Pytorch batch matrix vector outer product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054127/pytorch-batch-matrix-vector-outer-product) I have two matrices and would like to compute their outer product, or in other words the pairwise elementwise product.

Shape example:
If we have X1 and X2 of shapes of `torch.Size([32, 300, 8])`
The result should be of size `torch.Size([32, 300, 300, 8])`

Comment: How about `torch.einsum('bik,bjk->bijk', X1, X2)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add singleton dimensions:

```py
X1[:, None, ...] * X1[..., None, :]
```

But Usman Ali's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555134/pytorch-batch-matrix-matrix-outer-product#comment101572505_57555134) is also a good idea. Use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.einsum):

```py
torch.einsum('bik,bjk->bijk', X1, X2)
```